# Enviar email directamente desde la aplicación con un Intent

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando una aplicación para poder emitir un voto desde la tablet que tenemos todos los miembros de una asociación.

El código que les envío no me da ningún error de sintaxis, pero a la hora de ejecutar el botón que se supone que debe lanzar el e-mail, se me detiene la aplicación.

Esta es la parte final del código:

```
enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                enviaremail();
            }
            private  void enviaremail(){
                try {
                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");//enable STARTTLS
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "quioscocastelar@gmail.com");

                    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
                    session.setDebug(true);

                    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("quioscocastelar@gmail.com"));
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("taxi53badajoz@gmail.com"));
                    message.setSubject("VOTO");
                    message.setText("hola");

                    Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
                    t.connect("smtp.gmail.com","587","quioscocastelar@gmail.com");
                    t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                    t.close();

                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"correo no enviado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }


        });
```

Comment: perdon por el evio erroneo.

Comment: el codigo es la suma de la parte de arriba con la de abajo por este orden. gracias

Comment: La función enviaremail() creo que no hace falta que la declares dentro del listener del botón, prueba a sacarla fuera

Comment: Es importante agregues el mensaje de error descrito en el LogCat porque puede ser otro problema además del que es un poco obvio, la declaración del método private  void enviaremail(){ ,no debe estar dentro del listener. Probablemente obtendrías un error al compilar.

Comment: hola joacer. si saco la funcion enviaremail fuera, me da un error de sintaxis en el cierre del public void onclick, concretamente en el ultimo caracter, el punto y coma

Comment: no es solo fuera del listener es fuera del método donde defines el listener al botón. Agrega el código de tu clase. @boito

Comment: OK. arreglado. GRACIAS. ahora probaré si funciona

Comment: nada. sigue parandome la aplicacion al pulsar boton

Answer (score 3):

Es posible que sea debido a la versión de Android, las nuevas versiones tienen mas restricciones de seguridad y es posible que no te permitan enviar un email de esta manera por seguridad.

Para usar la manera estándar en Android puedes usar este método:

```
public static void sendEmail(Context context) {
        String text = "Your text";

        Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        mailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mailto@mailto.com"});
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        Intent mailChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Title");
        context.startActivity(mailChooserIntent);
    }
```

Esto solicita al sistema operativo abrir una aplicación para enviar un email pasándole a que correo quieres enviar el email y el asunto.

Igualmente, tu código debería estar estructurado así: (Como te ha comentado @Joacer)

```
enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                enviaremail();
            }
        });

private  void enviaremail(){
                try {
                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");//enable STARTTLS
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "quioscocastelar@gmail.com");

                    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
                    session.setDebug(true);

                    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("quioscocastelar@gmail.com"));
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("taxi53badajoz@gmail.com"));
                    message.setSubject("VOTO");
                    message.setText("hola");

                    Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
                    t.connect("smtp.gmail.com","587","quioscocastelar@gmail.com");
                    t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                    t.close();

                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"correo no enviado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Estas declarando incorrectamente el método, el método debe estar declarado a nivel de clase (como se declaran los métodos de la clase), no dentro del listener ni dentro del método donde se define el listener al botón. La configuración del listener del botón generalmente se realiza en un método por ejemplo `onCreate()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        ...

        enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                enviaremail();
            }
        });

    }


    private  void enviaremail(){
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");//enable STARTTLS
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "quioscocastelar@gmail.com");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            session.setDebug(true);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("quioscocastelar@gmail.com"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("taxi53badajoz@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("VOTO");
            message.setText("hola");

            Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
            t.connect("smtp.gmail.com","587","quioscocastelar@gmail.com");
            t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            t.close();

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"correo no enviado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

debes asegurar también que las credenciales,el puerto usado y la configuración usada es la correcta para el envío.

```
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");//enable STARTTLS
                    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "quioscocastelar@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Con el siguiente código también se controla si existe algún correo de email instalado en el dispositivo.

```
enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("message/rfc822");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"quioscocastelar@gmail.com"});
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "VOTO");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "hola");
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No hay instalada ninguna aplicación de correo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

            }
        });
```